# How do you redirect a button to open 2 url at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mailchimp

I want the MailChimp signup code with button below to open 2 URLs upon clicking the button, it should open:

- the MailChimp signup code on a new window
- open another url (e.g. google.com) on same window.

The MailChimp button is below

```
<div class="clear">
  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class=" submit- btn btn-default">Submit</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The snippet demo by stackoverflow won't work obviously because it's loaded in iframe. It'll however work for any webpage you directly write to.

```js
document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe').onclick = function() {
  window.open('http://google.com', '_blank'); // new window
  location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'; // same window
};
```

```html
<div id="mc-embedded-subscribe">Click me</div>
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by adding the following code in your button tag ...

```
onclick="window.open('https://login.mailchimp.com/signup'), window.location = 'https://google.com'"
```

so, the complete code would be ...

```
<div class="clear">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="submit- btn btn-default" onclick="window.open('https://login.mailchimp.com/signup'), window.location = 'https://google.com'">Submit</button>
</div>
```